# Why is it called nillable?

Tags: xsd

In an XML schema you can mark an element as `nillable` meaning it can take an explicit NULL value. See [nillable and minOccurs XSD element attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903062/nillable-and-minoccurs-xsd-element-attributes) for a great explanation.

What I'm curious about is **why** is it called `nillable`? I always see nillable and think it's a typo!

**EDIT**
I appreciate that `nil` is a synonym for `null`. What I'm wondering is why `nil` was chosen, rather than the more common (in computer science) `null`. Particularly as it should really be `nilable` (note the single L)!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> *What I'm wondering is why `nil` was chosen, rather than the more common (in computer science) `null`*

This depends on which part of computer science you're coming from!

If you look at programs written in functional languages, you'll see `nil` every where, and very seldom `null`. And as it happens, XML and all it's siblings such as XSLT are closely related to functional languages.

Comment: Ah, so it's idiomatic to functional people? That makes sense.

Answer (score 14):

Nil has the same language roots as null. Nil comes from the Latin for nihil which means "nothing". "Null", while related, comes from the Latin for "none" (literally 'ne-' meaning "not" and 'ullus' meaning "anything"). While they are similar in meaning, they have some slightly nuanced differences.

In practical usage, 'null' is far more common stateside while 'nil' is more common in Europe. Most people tend to use them interchangeably in software development terms but in language usage 'nil' is more common, in my experience.

Comment: I am a European and I didn't hear 'nil' from anyone

Comment: I still consider Great Britain to be part of Europe: https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/nil

Answer (score 5):

It comes from nil which is another term for null, used in XML. I don't think that there is any specific reason the one the be preferred over the other in different programming languages. It is just an expression. It is used in some sports too, to express 0. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nil

Answer (score 5):

If memory serves, it's called "nillable" because (some of) the SQL people in the room became concerned about possible confusion between the relevant concept in XSD and the relevant concept in SQL.  They threatened to lie down in the road to stop the proposal unless the name was changed.  So the WG changed the name.

(On the orthographic question, I think *nilable* would invite pronunciation with a long 'i'; I believe that both American and British English regularly double final single consonants following a short stressed vowel.  Cf. 'tag', 'tagging', 'tagged', 'taggable'.)

Answer (score -4):

This term we are using XML WSDL. If `nillable` is **true**, then we can also use **null** value in parameter. I used this and it worked for me.

Comment: This is not what he asked for.