# What is the difference b/w nullable keyword and nillable keyword in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, jaxb

Could you please any one explain what is the meaning of below declaration

```
@Column(nullable = false )
@XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true )
```

which means difference between nullable and nillable ?

Comment: It would help if you would add the import statements for the annotations as well.

Comment: `XmlElement` is not part of JPA, but instead it comes from JAXB. So the two annotations and their `nullable` and `nillable` elements are unrelated. Having said this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913200/why-is-it-called-nillable explains why `nillable` is used in the context of XML (which JAXB deals with).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@Column` annotation comes from JPA (the Java Persistence API) and specifies how a field is mapped to a database column. Using the `nullable` attribute of the annotation, you specify whether `NULL` values should be allowed in the database for this field.

The `@XmlElement` annotation comes from JAXB (the Java API for XML Binding) and specifies how the field should be treated when converting this object to and from XML. If you set the `nillable` attribute to `true`, it means that in the XML it's allowed for the corresponding element to have an `xsi:nil="true"` attribute.

Note that in XML there are subtle differences between an XML element being not present, being present but with an empty value and having an `xsi:nil` attribute.

Whether it's appropriate to use an `@XmlElement` annotation with `nillable = true` attribute depends on the requirements for your application.

Comment: @Jasper, In my entity class we have declared @Column(nullable=false) in that circumstances null values are allowed to persists in db or not  ?

Comment: If you set `nullable = false` in the `@Column` annotation, then obviously `NULL` values in the database are not allowed.